# Is there a formatting flag that converts to a lowercase String in Java?

Tags: java, string-formatting

There are two placeholders in Java that convert to a String:

- `%s` -- converts to a String as-is
- `%S` -- converts to an Uppercase String.

Thus, given:

```
String result = String.format(template, "Hi James!");
```

- If template = `"%s"`, the result will be `"Hi James!"`
- If template = `"%S"`, the result will be  `"HI JAMES!"`

Question:

Generally, is there a way to convert an argument to a lowercase String using only Java's format conversion syntax?  (In other words, without using `toLowerCase()`.)
Specifically, is there any possible value for `template` such that the result will be `"hi james!"`?

Comment: I don't think such a conversion exists currently.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, there is not. But, according to [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

> Conversions denoted by an upper-case character (i.e. 'B', 'H', 'S', 'C', 'X', 'E', 'G', 'A', and 'T') are the same as those for the corresponding lower-case conversion characters except that the result is converted to upper case according to the rules of the prevailing `Locale`. **The result is equivalent to the following invocation of `String.toUpperCase()`**

In other words, the following

```
String result = String.format("%S", "Hi James!");
```

is equivalent to

```
String result = String.format("%s", "Hi James!").toUpperCase();
```

So, if you want to get a lower case string, you can just do:

```
String result = String.format("%s", "Hi James!").toLowerCase();
```

There won't be an optimization by doing the conversion using a flag.

Comment: Possibly more useful: `String.format("%s", "Hi James!".toLowerCase())` -- since if your format is e.g. `"The message was: %s"` you probably don't want to lowercase the whole thing.

Comment: Only the 1st sentence is useful ("no there is not"). The rest just paraphrases the question and proposes what @James wants to avoid.